# C++ #include Loop

Tags: c++, loops, include

**File Dog.h**

```
#ifndef DOG_H
#define DOG_H

#include "Cat.h"
//class Cat;

class Dog
{
        Cat c;
};

#endif
```

**File Cat.h**

```
#ifndef CAT_H
#define CAT_H

#include "Dog.h"
//class Dog;

class Cat
{
        Dog d;
};

#endif
```

This causes a loop, the problem is that both classes needs to know about each other; forward declaration doesn't solve the problem either. You can create a pointer of either Dog d or Cat c to solve it.

Question: Is there really no way of not creating a pointer, i.e keep the code as it is without rewrite of how I want it to be?

Comment: why forward declaration doesn't solve it?

Comment: Answer: No. How would you construct an object which contains itself? You should also rethink your design if you believe you need this sort of thing.

Comment: This can't be how you want it to be since, even if you could resolve the declaration order, it's logically impossible for each class to contain the other. One will have to have a pointer or reference; and that one will not need to include the header.

Comment: If this was nontrivial - i.e. a `Cat` also had some variable beyond a `Dog`, and a `Dog` something beyond just a `Cat`, wouldn't this be an infinite recursion so that the size of the object would in fact be infinite?

Comment: This particular code was an example to get the idea across, originally the issue arrived from inheriting say Dog in Cat, and having an object of Cat in Dog.

Comment: You could have each class contain a pointer to the other class instead, and initialize each at a latter point. The way you don't immediately run into an infinite construction. I don't think is a very good design, but if you need to, this should work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're trying to do is impossible. Your class would take infinite space.

You got a `Dog` which has a `Cat` member variable, which has a `Dog` member variable, which has a `Cat` member variable, which has a `Dog` member variable...

Without breaking it somewhere with a pointer you'll end up with infinite recursive member variables taking infinite memory which is not possible.

Note that the compiler can't even actually calculate the memory needed for `Dog` or `Cat` due to the infinite recursion. But since a class in C++ can't be `0` size normally, we know that it'll be infinite space anyways.

The other answers give nice perspectives too, i.e. 'Chicken and Egg' problem of which one has to be defined first to be able to define the other.

---

I just wanna add that mutually recursive classes are something strange and best avoided if you can design it some other way. If you really have to use them make sure that you actually break the recursiveness. Otherwise you shift it only from an error at compile time due to infinite mutual recursion to running out of memory and an crash at runtime if you got a naive implementation with pointers that does infinite mutually recursive `new` calls at construction time.

Comment: this is true. But I think that is not the cause of the error, look at my answer (please correct me if I am wrong)

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible, and it has nothing to do with include files.

The reason is that if you create a class which contains another class as a member (rather than a pointer), the compiler needs to add some space for that class into the other class. E.g., if you create something like this:

```
class Dog {
  std::string name;
  std::string owner;
};

class Person {
    Dog pet;
    std::string name;
};
```

Then instances of the class `Person` in the above example have a size that is `sizeof(std::string) + sizeof(Dog)`, while instances of the class `Dog` have a size that is `sizeof(std::string) * 2`; so Person is `sizeof(std::string) * 3` in size (modulo alignment differences)

In other words, the memory required for a first-class variable (as opposed to a pointer) in C++ is assigned *as part of* the instance, and is not a pointer; this works very much the same way as `struct`s do. In fact, there really is no practical difference between the `class` and `struct` keywords in C++, other than the fact that a class is `private` by default, whereas a struct is `public`.

Answer (score 1):

Besides this leading to an infinite space object (as Raphael explains), the compiler won't let this happen as explained in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341198/forward-declaration-of-class-function). He doesn't know about `Cat` class when you are using it in `Dog` class, so it won't work for the same reason that this won't work :

```
class B;
class A{
    B b;
};
```

Comment: Another way of seeing it. I guess this could be expanded to the 'chicken and egg' problem since one class has to be defined first before you can define the other, but you can't say which one.

Comment: @RaphaelMiedl Correct

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out, you cannot directly or indirectly define an object that has itself as a member without indirection.

If you only want the ability to use the `.` syntax instead of the `->` syntax, you can use a reference instead of a pointer. For example:

```
// in Dog.h
class Cat;

class Dog {
public:
    std::unique_ptr<Cat> catp;
    Cat &c;
    Dog ();
    Dog (Cat &);
};

// in Cat.h
class Cat {
public:
    std::unique_ptr<Dog> dogp;
    Dog &d;
    Cat ();
    Cat (Dog &);
}
```

Now, in your source code, you can do something like this:

```
#include "Dog.h"
#include "Cat.h"

Dog::Dog () : catp(new Cat(*this)), c(*catp) {}
Cat::Cat () : dogp(new Dog(*this)), d(*dogp) {}

Dog::Dog (Cat &cat) : c(cat) {}
Cat::Cat (Dog &dog) : d(dog) {}
```

Comment: I just wanna add a warning that this should be only thought of as an example. A naive implementation will only shift the compile time problem to infinite mutually recursive `new` calls at construction time. Take care that you really have a way to break the recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Use pointers instead.

The problem is that in order for the precompiler to know the memory size of `Dog`, it also needs to know how much memory to allocate for `Cat`. However, `Cat` needs to know how much memeory `Dog` use, and you'll get an infinite loop.

If you want `Cat` to know of `Dog` and `Dog` know of `Cat`, use pointers instead of an object. This is because pointers always have the same memory size, so the precompiler won't need to scan `Cat.h` to "learn" how much memory it must allocate for it. In other words, it already knows how much memory it needs, so it avoids the problem.

Tip:
If you have dozens or hundreds of classes which should all know of each other, you'll run into a loop hierarchy of doom. There is a way to avoid all of this and save you a headache on big c++ projects:

Make a `PreDefine.h` header where you predefine all classes based on some precompiler rules (and only use pointers). You can then include `PreDefine.h` anywhere you need it. Such, you can create hundreds of classes which all link to each other and you still won't run into a include-loop error.

In this example we have a `Cat`, `Dog` and a `Mouse` class, but there can be as many classes as you want.

In PreDefine.h:

```
#pragma once

#if !defined Dog_H && !defined Dog_TEMP
#define Dog_TEMP
class Dog;
#endif

#if !defined Cat_H && !defined Cat_TEMP
#define Cat_TEMP
class Cat;
#endif

#if !defined Mouse_H && !defined Mouse_TEMP
#define Mouse_TEMP
class Mouse;
#endif

//...

//this pattern for each class you have

//...
```

In Dog.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "PreDefine.h" // <-- include this in all header files, and all your problems goes away.
class Dog
{
    Cat * c;  // <- must be a pointer
    Mouse * m; // <- must be a pointer
};
#define Dog_H // <- need this at end of class to stop any future overwrites of class.
```

In Dog.cpp:

```
#include "Cat.h" //<-- Include real header in .cpp files where you need it
#include "Mouse.h"//<-- Include real header in .cpp files where you need it

... your code here...
```

Use the same pattern in Cat.h, Cat.cpp, Mouse.h and Mouse.cpp.

In Cat.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "PreDefine.h"
class Cat
{
    Dog * d;  
    Mouse * m; 
};
#define Cat_H
```

In Mouse.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "PreDefine.h"
class Mouse
{
    Cat * c;  
    Dog * d; 
};
#define Mouse_H
```

In Cat.cpp:

```
#include "Dog.h" 
#include "Mouse.h"
```

In Mouse.cpp:

```
#include "Cat.h" 
#include "Dog.h"
```